# Firebase - Getting profile photo url from auth having Facebook provider after Graph 8.0 update

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Facebook login for firebase auth for my android app and retriving user's photourl using

```
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()
```

This gives me the photo url from the user's facebook profile.

Recently I have received mail from Facebook stating -
"Facebook will now require client or app access tokens to access a user’s profile picture when querying against user IDs. Beginning on October 24, 2020, queries for profile pictures made against user IDs without an access token will return a generic silhouette rather than a profile picture."
More on it on this link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/08/04/Introducing-graph-v8-marketing-api-v8

My question -

Does the request `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()` use access tokens to access url from facebook and will it function the same after the release of Graph API 8.0 on 24th Oct?
Or will I have to make a different query request to fetch the User's photo url for facebook provider?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson
No answers yet !!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you'll have to add the access token to the photo url by yourself as Firebase does not and will not support it (as they don't have access to it - you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6829)).

You'll have to do something along the lines of:

```
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl() + "?access_token=<facebook_access_token>"
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get the access token of facebook, after being logged-in with Firebase, you can use:

`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`

Complementing the answer of [Marek Fort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4975152/marek-fo%C5%99t), with Kotlin you can get the picture doing something like that:

```
"${firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()}?access_token=${AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()}"
```

Comment: What is `AccessToken`?

Comment: You have to import it like that `import com.facebook.AccessToken`. From `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for 2023** when working with firebase "Web Modular API"

The profile url can be obtained with the method

```
getAdditionalUserInfo(result);
```

Here is the full implementation:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
  getAdditionalUserInfo,
} from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  authDomain: 'xxx',
  projectId: 'xxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
  appId: 'xxx',
  measurementId: 'xxx',
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();

let result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

let additional = getAdditionalUserInfo(result);
console.log('picture_url: ', additional.profile.data.picture.url);

// if token is needet
const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
console.log('credential: ', credential);
```

reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login?hl=de#web-modular-api_4

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin it looks like:

```
"${firebaseAuth.currentUser?.photoUrl}?access_token=${AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()?.token}"
```